# “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error after installing VMware tools

Tags: graphics, vmware

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on VMware Workstation 12 and I have also installed VMware tools in order to run Ubuntu in fullscreen. After installation of a couple of libraries like tensorflow, I rebooted the system and it showed the following error message while it was just working fine before rebooting:

```
**The system is running in low-graphics mode**

Your screen, graphics cards, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.
```

I have been trying all the solution offers I have read from related posts but none of them worked well. One of those solutions caused a login loop problem and then I reinstalled Ubuntu. I personally think the problem might be relevant with installing VMware tools but I am not really sure as I am new to Linux. I use Nvidia GTX 1050. I would appreciate all the help I can get with this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same situation/problem, on VMware Workstation 14 and Ubuntu 16.04, by updating the OS:

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo reboot

The above commands solved my issue - and I tried reinstalling desktop, reviewing logs and config files... Nothing else helped me.

Answer (score 0):

I carried out a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 and `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` then `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools`, rebooted and came across the same problem using ESXi.

To solve the issue, I made sure the 3D acceleration was checked. In ESXi, you have the option of specifying the video memory too, which is 16MB.

Steps you could try are these:

1. Start with a fresh installation, make sure the 3D acceleration checked, once installation is complete take a snapshot.
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools`
4. `sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop`
5. Reboot the VM (you should have fullscreen after reboot)
6. `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Finally reboot the VM again.

That is exactly what I carried out.